# Canvas background image not showing on opening webpage

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, background-image

I am creating a canvas to display captcha in it using javascript. The problem is I want to add a background to it but the background does not load on opening the page. However, when I hit the refresh button it works fine. Here's the code:

```html
<script>
    var code = {};
    function canvas(){

         var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var background = new Image();
            background.src = "http://gazell.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image011.png";
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0 ,0);
        var list = new Array('@','%','#','$','*','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');                   
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<6;i++){
          var a = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var b = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var c = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var d = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var e = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var f = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var g = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
         }
       code.value = a  + b + c +  d + e + f + g;

       ctx.font = "italic 42px verdana";
       ctx.fillStyle="#FF9912";
       ctx.textAlign = "center";
       ctx.fillText(code.value, canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    }

    window.onload = canvas();

    function ValidCaptcha(){
       //var string1 = document.getElementById('canvas').value;
       var string1 = document.getElementById('text').value;
       var string2 = code.value;
       if(string1 != null){
           if(string1 == string2){
           alert("true");
       }else{
           alert("false");
        }
       }  
    }     

</script>
```

I want the code to display the canvas background when the page is loaded not when I hit the refresh button

```html
<body onload="canvas();">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Testing Captcha</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="80" width="260"></canvas>
    <input id="text" type="text"></input>
    <button id="btn" onclick="canvas();">Refresh</button>
    <button type="button" value="Check" onclick="ValidCaptcha();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is that script loaded in? And why are you setting both, the window.onload and the body.onload to canvas()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in your action trying to set the background image of canvas before image is loaded or its content is retrieved.

to solve this issue you need to first create your image element and on its onload event you can draw the canvas.

i've attached  a working version of your work, also make sure script is your last element in HTML body

```html
<body onload="canvas();">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Testing Captcha</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="80" width="260"></canvas>
    <input id="text" type="text"></input>
    <button id="btn" onclick="canvas();">Refresh</button>
    <button type="button" value="Check" onclick="ValidCaptcha();">Submit</button>
  </div>

</body>
<script>
    var code = {};
    function canvas(){
            
     var createdImage = drawImage();
      //wait till image is loaded then draw canvas
      createdImage.onload = function(){
          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
           var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
           
            ctx.drawImage(createdImage, 0 ,0);
        var list = new Array('@','%','#','$','*','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');                   
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<6;i++){
          var a = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var b = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var c = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var d = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var e = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var f = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
          var g = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
         }
       code.value = a  + b + c +  d + e + f + g;

       ctx.font = "italic 42px verdana";
       ctx.fillStyle="#FF9912";
       ctx.textAlign = "center";
       ctx.fillText(code.value, canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
      }
       
    }

  var hiddenImg = document.getElementById('loadedImg');
  window.onLoad = canvas();
  
   

    function ValidCaptcha(){
       //var string1 = document.getElementById('canvas').value;
       var string1 = document.getElementById('text').value;
       var string2 = code.value;
       if(string1 != null){
           if(string1 == string2){
           alert("true");
       }else{
           alert("false");
        }
       }  
    } 
  //Draw image in seprate method
  function drawImage(){
     var background = new Image();
     background.src = "https://rrraul.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/projpanel_illust_random-1.jpg";
    
    return background;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @ElvenStar for the fast Reply as i just created my stackoverflow account this evening and getting a working reply on first day feels really good.

Comment: Glad that helped :)